# How to have a unique identifier under the same foreign key on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, identity

I am having two tables a Case Table and a Message Table.
A Case might have a number of messages.
However the messages should have a refence field like "Case No/Msg No" and Msg No should be on a sequence starding from 1 for all the messages under the same case.

*Example:*
Case 1 Msg 1 --> Ref: 1/1
Case 1 Msg 2 --> Ref: 1/2 
Case 2 Msg 1 --> Ref: 2/1

Message No should be a sequence but only for the messages under the same case.
My problem is how I create the MsgNo? 
System will be multi-user so I cannot use a get max function to do this.
Just to mention that I am using SQL Server 2008. 
Is there any other way to implement this using the IDENTITY function maybe?
Any ideas are welcome

Thanks for any help in advance 
M.A

Comment: Do you **need** to store this number, or could it be computed when you *select* the rows from the database (this second option is a lot easier to implement, and can even be stable provided deletions never occur)

Comment: I need to store this number. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create Master/Detail table structure. Both tables should have their own ID (its always better to work with normilized database). Then create the "LineNumber" in the Detail table and increment it in accordance with the Master Table id. This is similar to the LineNumber in the Document lines. For examle you have Invoice and the Invoice lines, each line have it's own id and there are more one field to identify Invoice Line.

Comment: Daria thanks for your reply. I cannot however understand how this solution will help me, I already have a Master/Detail table structure. But I don't know how to create this LineNumber you mention. Is not a db INTENTITY as fas as I can understand.

Comment: Not, it isn't Identity field. It's incremental field you manage on your insert routine. Something like MAX(MsgNumber) + 1 .... WHERE CaseId = X

Comment: Because this is a ,multiuser environment I cannot use a MAX function as a number of users might add messages to the same case.So I need to find a way to ensure the uniqueness of this MsgNo and avoid any duplicate errors as there is a unique index on this field.

Comment: your insert should be made in some stored procedure and you will calculate your MAX there, right before you insert the value to the table... This way you will have no risk to insert duplicate values.

Comment: @DariaBarteneva - if you'd said "transaction", rather than "stored procedure", I might agree with your statement - although it would have to be "transaction, with suitable isolation". Stored procedures don't, by themselves, offer any particular concurrency/isolation benefits.

Comment: If I use SP with Transaction inside how I make sure that no other process is calling that SP? Is it possible to have this isolation on Code level in my system and not in DB?

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I will try this and let u know ;)